# Query Regarding Solana Contribution Cap Implementation

Tags: spl-token

We're exploring the implementation of a crucial feature for Solana-based project. Would it be possible to make a mechanism that enforces an individual contribution cap to a liquidity pool? This is vital for fairness in the distribution of tokens within the Solana ecosystem.

Looking forward to your insights.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! You'll need to write your own on-chain program to enforce the caps, but it's definitely doable.

If you maintain a deposit record account for each wallet that deposits into the pool, then you can track how much they've put in, and stop them from depositing too much.